# How do I get a Java Set to iterate in the same order every time?

Tags: java

Is there any way that I can get a Java Set object (not a SortedSet) to iterate over its elements in the same order every time that I run the program. (The elements are the same for each run.) I am trying to debug my program but I'm having trouble reproducing my error because the iterator returns the values in a different order each time. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`LinkedHashSet` iterates in insertion order.

See the javadocs for more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Answer (score 2):

Use a `LinkedHashSet` and the iteration order should be the same (it is just a HashSet backed by a LinkedList).